# jquery if statement and event-handling

Tags: jquery

I have a `<div>`, containing two `<i>`s and an `<img>`:

```
<div id="lighbox">
   <i class="icon-chevron-sign-left"></i>
   <img src="#">
   <i class="icon-chevron-sign-right"></i>
</div>
```

With jQuery, I added an event listener to `#lightbox i`:

```
$('#lightbox i').click(function(){
        var direction = $(this).attr('class');
        if (direction = 'icon-chevron-sign-left'){
            alert('left');
        }else if(direction  ='icon-chevron-sign-right'){                
                alert('right');
        }
});
```

When I open up the page, and click on the left sign, I get an alert sayin `left`. But, I still get an alert saying left if I click on the right sign. Furthermore, when I write `$('#lightbox i').attr('class')` in the console, I only get:

```
"icon-chevron-sign-left"
```

Shouldn't it have given me both left and right? I mean when I just write `$('#lightbox i')`, I get :

```
[<i class=​"icon-chevron-sign-left">​</i>,<i class=​"icon-chevron-sign-right">​</i>​]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with `=`  you have to use `==`

```
=  for assignment 


==  for checking the values equal or not..
```

Try

```
 if (direction == 'icon-chevron-sign-left'){
            alert('left');
        }else if(direction  =='icon-chevron-sign-right'){                
                alert('right');
        }
```

[**Javascript Operators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Comment: It is a syntax error. This question is not eligible according to the rules.

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar  Not knowing the difference and syntax mistakes are not same.

Comment: Syntax error occurs only when programmer is unaware of what he is typing or did it by mistake :P

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar  :)  `did by mistake` , Corrected here.

Comment: Well, I did know the difference between == and =, but I make too many simple mistakes sometimes. May I ask the difference between == and === ?

Comment: :) happens to  Every programmer some times. Yes `===` called as strict equal.I attached the docs relative to it .There you can find the full description with examples.

Answer (score 1):

in javascript you should use === instead of =

```
if(exp === check)
{
    // do something
}
```